# onDragStart returns a different marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an Android application using the google-map's libraries.
The main problem is managing a mapping between (latutide, longitude) coordinates and Integers.
So inside the Activity, I have an `HashMap<LatLng,Integer>` object called `dict` which does the work.

I present the content of `dict` to the user putting `Marker` object on the map, and when the user select a new marker I show the associated integer in a label.

All is working fine, except for the drag and drop functionality.

```
GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener onMarkerDragListener = new   
GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {

        private int content;

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker1) {
            content = dict.remove(marker1.getPosition()); // NULL
        }

        ...

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker2) {
            dict.put(marker2.getPosition(), content);
        }
    };
```

The error is on the line commented with "NULL", where the marker selected for the dragging called `marker1`, has a position (`LatLng` object) which is not a key of the `dict` mapping.

My impression is that when the user select a marker for the dragging, the system delete this one and return a new marker with a slightly different position.

This seems unreal... How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not on marker returned by the drag listener, but on the fact that you are using the LatLng as a key of the dict instead of the marker itself (or the markerID).
The documentation is not clear, but I'm quite confident that getPosition() gives you a copy of the position, and the remove function uses the '==' method instead of the "equals".
So my advice is to use the whole marker as dict key (which would be better, and you can retrieve the location whenever you want), or use the markerID as key of the dict (but this can change), by using:

```
myMarker.getId()
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#getId()

Comment: Nice solution applied in 10 seconds!